# Apache Camel Mina2 not receiving data using Socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, apache-camel, mina

I have been trying to send data through socket programming to **Apache Camel** and I am trying to use **Apache Mina2**.  The idea is to send the data over TCP to Camel. For TCP, I am using socket programing. This is what my code is for **Mina2**:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
from("mina2:tcp://localhost:6789?sync=false")
    .process(new LogProcessor());
}
```

**LogProcessor** only prints the body of the received message using `exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)`

This piece of code works fine with Apache **Mina** as below:

```
from("mina:tcp://localhost:6789?textline=true&sync=true")
    .process(new LogProcessor());
```

The socket programming client code that I am using is as below:

```
  try
      {
         Socket client = new Socket();




         client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 6789));

         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
         System.out.println("After Dataoutput stream");
         out.writeBytes("Content gets received in server\n");

         client.close();
      }
```

The same piece of code works fine for **Mina** but does not work with **Mina2**.
I am unable to figure out what is causing the problem. Do I need to add some parameters in the from clause of Camel.

Kindly help..

Comment: Did you try adding the `textline=true` parameter?

Comment: Yes, I tried with  from("mina2:tcp://localhost:6789?textline=true"). But this didnt work :(

Comment: What's the exact problem? Can you tell if Is the server receiving the request? Does the client receive a response at all? Can you check if the server is listening on the socket?

Comment: Yes, The server is listening to the socket and there is a network traffic. The same piece of code works with Mina but does not with Mina2. It keeps on waiting at the input for the data and does not perform the next action once data comes

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by mina2 consumer doesn't take the response from the in message. You need to setup the out message in your LogProcessor just like this.

```
 exchange.getOut().getBody("response message");
```

Comment: I tried with that as well. Infact getBody takes a CLASS argument and not the string. This is not working :( . Camel's website has an example with getin as well.